# Howto use Hibernate StatelessSession in SpringBatch Writer

Tags: java, hibernate, batch-processing, spring-batch

is there a way to use a `StatelessSession` within a spring-batch Writer which is taking part of the current spring-batch JDBC-Transaction and Hibernate-Transaction?

I tried

```
public class MyWriter implements ItemWriter<SomeClass> {
    @Override
    public void write(final List<? extends SomeClass> items) throws Exception {
        StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        for(SomeCLass item : items){
            session.insert(item);
        }
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

but actually it is creating a new HibernateSession outside from the session handled by spring-batch. How to get the `StatelessSession` being attached to the current statefull-`Session`.

Background: I would love to use a stateless-session because the method `myStatefullHibernateSession.save(item)` is loading associated objects that are also not part of the session. I am doing so in order to minimize the number of sqls created and in my batch-environment this is saving a lot cpu-costs and is reducing runtime while processing millions  of data-records.

Hibernate: 3.6.10
Spring-Batch: 2.2.0

**edit:** With the help of `axtavt` I got it working to use the same JDBC-Transaction but I am using in addition the hibernate property `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` which causes the following observation:

1. If using `beginTransaction` and `commit` on the created `StatelessSession` the transaction-control of spring-batch is not working any more (later exceptions in the writer wont rollback)
2. If not creating a hibernate-transaction on the `StatelessSession` the transaction-control of spring-batch will work but a spring-batch-commit will not commit the insert/update/delete-statements lying in the `BatchingBatcher` of Hibernate in the `StatelessSession`.

To sum it up: I just need a `StatelessSession` instead of the standard-hibernate stateful-`Session` in my writer.

Answer (score 0):

If Spring Batch uses regular Spring transaction management (`HibernateTransactionManager`, etc), then you can try to obtain `Connection` bound to the current transaction using `DataSourceUtils` and use it when opening `StatelessSession`:

```
Connection c = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession(c);
```

You may need to make `HibernateTransactionManager` aware of the `DataSource` that you use to create `SessionFactory`, see [`HibernateTransactionManager.setDataSource()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTransactionManager.html#setDataSource%28javax.sql.DataSource%29).

Comment: a good idea but sadly not working properly in my case. This creates a StatelessSession bound to the current connection and sql-transaction. In my case I am using the hibernate property `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` which is set to >50 . This causes the problem that all insert/update/delete-statements that are currently lying in the statelesssession-jdbc-batch are not being committed when finishing the writer-method because the sql-transaction is being comitted but not the stateless-session which is waiting for committing the jdbc-batch-package. (I will adjust my question)